# Laravel HTTP Client dynamic call HTTP Method

Tags: laravel

I want to make all requests dynamic rather than defining `Http` in each function followed by httpMethod like this.

```
Http::post()
Http::put()
Http::delete()
```

what i tried.

```
function send($method, $url) {
   Http::withToken($token)->{$method}($url)
}

function x() {
   return $this->send('GET', 'url')
}
```

My code above works fine and i dont know if `call a function` from `variable output` like `{$method}` is best practice. but I want something similar like `Guzzle`.

```
(new Client)->request($method, $url, $options)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you take a look at the source code here https://github.com/illuminate/http/blob/a28981924d318272053b87712740868d9b44899e/Client/PendingRequest.php laravel is using Guzzle. so basicly Http Client is Guzzle.

and every function like `POST` `PUT` etc call a function name `send`

so you can just direct call `send` function like this.

```
Http::withToken($token)
    ->send('POST', 'url', [
        'headers' => [...]
        'form_params' => [
            ...
        ]
    ])
```

Comment: The 'form_params' key actually depends on the body format, make sure you were using the same key as the value of 'bodyFormat' variable, possible values: form_params, json, body, multipart

https://github.com/illuminate/http/blob/master/Client/PendingRequest.php#L331

Answer (score 2):

you need to accept that param like

```php
function send($method,$url) {
   retrun Http::withToken($token)->{$method}($url)
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add param in my question. i;ve edited my questiion

Comment: @Hafizu add `retrun` in `Http`